# SQLite: Remove HTML comments from text body

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

I have a database with data that is in html format.

Is there an update query I can use which will remove all the HTML comments from it?

```
<!-- Some comment -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite has very limited string manipulation. I strongly suggest taking a platform with a good connector (like .NET) and going through your list, updating one-by-one. Use a regex (egad!) or something appropriate to remove the HTML comments.